# std::vector< T >::iterator with accessible constructor

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

*g++* implementation of *STL* allows me in my client code to construct an iterator of `std::vector<T>::iterator` type with arbitrary address value:

```
int* i_ptr;
std::vector< int >::iterator it(i_ptr);
```

Is it standard ability, or just rudiment of implementation?

Where it designed to be used?

Comment: The standard does not define it as a required feature.

In fact such a construction should be private, accessible from `std::vector` only, via `friend`ship.

The standard does not even deny that to happen (so -probably- we cannot sustain it is a *defect*, but may be someone can report it as such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an implementation detail, it is not even guaranteed to compile by the standard. It is also not listed in gcc's implementation defined behavior nor in the GNU C++ extensions, so your snippet may break at any version change.

Don't rely on this "working" in any sense in your code.

Comment: btw, where are described the requirements to containers iterator in Standard.?

Comment: @GreenTree Chapter 23 of the C++14 standard or cppreference.com The former is more formal, the latter more useful in everyday use.

Comment: As a remark, iirc Chandler Carruth once said that libc++ guarantees `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be `T*` for `T!=bool` as implementation defined behavior, but I cannot find any documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 RC this does not compile:

```
main.cpp(8): error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>::
_Vector_iterator(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>> &&)':
cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to
'const std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>> &'
```

Comment: It looks like a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Also you should at least specify if you are in Debug or Release mode because the result may vary depending on it.

Comment: I'd say it's fine. This is not [tag:language-lawyer], so a major modern platform not compiling the code demonstrates that the snippet is not portable standard C++ just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is a standard ability. Just an implementation defined feature.

In many implementations *vector* iterators are just simple pointers. So if you have a *vector< T >* then iterator is simply a pointer to type *T*. It is done for some optimization purposes.

In such implementations it is possible to create iterators initialized from the pointers to type *T* because you can initialize a pointer to type *T* by another pointer of such type.

But it is implementation defined, of course, if an iterator defined as a pointer to type *T* or not.